# Как форму созданную в Qt Designer начинить логикой действий?

Tags: python, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, pyside6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Я сделал простенький дизайн приложения в *Qt Designer*.

[image: Программа]

Что должно происходить:

Пользователь вводит цифру
(условно она кладется в переменную "a")

```
a = float(input(' '))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем при нажатии на кнопку "Рассчитать" питон производит расчет по формуле :

```
(str(round(0.3 * a / 100 * 11.5, 2)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выводит результат в это окошко.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код с Qt Designer

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
                        QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
                        QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
                       QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
                       QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
                       QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow,
                           QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget)


class Ui_main_w(object):
    def setupUi(self, main_w):
        if not main_w.objectName():
            main_w.setObjectName(u"main_w")
    main_w.resize(560, 440)
    main_w.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 440))
    main_w.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 440))
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    main_w.setWindowIcon(icon)
    self.all_w = QWidget(main_w)
    self.all_w.setObjectName(u"all_w")
    self.le_summer = QLineEdit(self.all_w)
    self.le_summer.setObjectName(u"le_summer")
    self.le_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 50, 241, 31))
    self.le_summer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
    self.le_summer.setMaxLength(10)
    self.le_summer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.le_summer.setDragEnabled(False)
    self.out_summer = QLabel(self.all_w)
    self.out_summer.setObjectName(u"out_summer")
    self.out_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 140, 241, 281))
    self.out_summer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);")
    self.out_summer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
    self.btn_summer = QPushButton(self.all_w)
    self.btn_summer.setObjectName(u"btn_summer")
    self.btn_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 90, 241, 41))
    self.btn_summer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
    self.btn_summer.setStyleSheet(u"")
    self.btn_winter = QPushButton(self.all_w)
    self.btn_winter.setObjectName(u"btn_winter")
    self.btn_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 90, 241, 41))
    self.btn_winter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
    self.out_winter = QLabel(self.all_w)
    self.out_winter.setObjectName(u"out_winter")
    self.out_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 140, 241, 281))
    self.out_winter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);")
    self.out_winter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
    self.le_winter = QLineEdit(self.all_w)
    self.le_winter.setObjectName(u"le_winter")
    self.le_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 50, 241, 31))
    self.le_winter.setMaxLength(10)
    self.label_summer = QLabel(self.all_w)
    self.label_summer.setObjectName(u"label_summer")
    self.label_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 241, 21))
    self.label_summer.setStyleSheet(u"")
    self.label_winter = QLabel(self.all_w)
    self.label_winter.setObjectName(u"label_winter")
    self.label_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 20, 241, 21))
    self.label_winter.setStyleSheet(u"")
    main_w.setCentralWidget(self.all_w)

    self.retranslateUi(main_w)

    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main_w)

# setupUi

def retranslateUi(self, main_w):
    main_w.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", u"BenzConfig", None))
    self.le_summer.setText("")
    self.out_summer.setText("")
    self.btn_summer.setText(
        QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
    self.btn_winter.setText(
        QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
    self.out_winter.setText("")
    self.le_winter.setText("")
    self.label_summer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
    self.label_winter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
# retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда не изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА.

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Кнопка излучает сигнал [**clicked()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), когда она активируется мышью,
клавишей пробела или сочетанием клавиш. 
Подключитесь к этому сигналу, чтобы выполнить действие кнопки.

Установите свои импорты и попробуйте:

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, 
    QLocale, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, 
    QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget)
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_main_w(object):
    def setupUi(self, main_w):
        if not main_w.objectName():
            main_w.setObjectName(u"main_w")
        main_w.resize(560, 440)
        main_w.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 440))
        main_w.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 440))
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        main_w.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.all_w = QWidget(main_w)
        self.all_w.setObjectName(u"all_w")
        self.le_summer = QLineEdit(self.all_w)
        self.le_summer.setObjectName(u"le_summer")
        self.le_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 50, 241, 31))
        self.le_summer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.le_summer.setMaxLength(10)
        self.le_summer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.le_summer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.out_summer = QLabel(self.all_w)
        self.out_summer.setObjectName(u"out_summer")
        self.out_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 140, 241, 281))
        self.out_summer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);")
        self.out_summer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btn_summer = QPushButton(self.all_w)
        self.btn_summer.setObjectName(u"btn_summer")
        self.btn_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 90, 241, 41))
        self.btn_summer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn_summer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btn_winter = QPushButton(self.all_w)
        self.btn_winter.setObjectName(u"btn_winter")
        self.btn_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 90, 241, 41))
        self.btn_winter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.out_winter = QLabel(self.all_w)
        self.out_winter.setObjectName(u"out_winter")
        self.out_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 140, 241, 281))
        self.out_winter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);")
        self.out_winter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.le_winter = QLineEdit(self.all_w)
        self.le_winter.setObjectName(u"le_winter")
        self.le_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 50, 241, 31))
        self.le_winter.setMaxLength(10)
        self.label_summer = QLabel(self.all_w)
        self.label_summer.setObjectName(u"label_summer")
        self.label_summer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 241, 21))
        self.label_summer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.label_winter = QLabel(self.all_w)
        self.label_winter.setObjectName(u"label_winter")
        self.label_winter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 20, 241, 21))
        self.label_winter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        main_w.setCentralWidget(self.all_w)

        self.retranslateUi(main_w)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main_w)

    def retranslateUi(self, main_w):
        main_w.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.le_summer.setText("")
        self.out_summer.setText("")
        self.btn_summer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
            u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.btn_winter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
            u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.out_winter.setText("")
        self.le_winter.setText("")
        self.label_summer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
            u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.label_winter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_w", 
            u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))

# Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, 
# и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
# -------------> vvvvvvvvvvv  vvvvvvvvv <--------------------------------- # !!!
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_main_w):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                 # !!! +++
        
        #
        # тут ваша логика
        #
        
        self.btn_summer.clicked.connect(self.func_summer)
        
    def func_summer(self):
        try:
            a_summer = float(self.le_summer.text())
            self.out_summer.setText(f'{a_summer}')
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                f"Что-то пошло не так. \nПроверьте исходные данные.\n{e}\n")
             

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
А подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно прописать логику?
К примеру, вот такая формула как может выглядеть в коде?

0.3 * a / 100 * 11.5

Comment: @Vadim пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. То что вы спрашиваете , будет выглядеть так как вы написали. Вам надо попробовать и если что-то не будет получаться - задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я совсем новичек и не понимаю куда вставить формулу которая делает расчет при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @Vadim то, что вы новичек,  не есть проблема. Проблема в том, что вы не желаете попробовать вставить формулу. Еще раз прочитайте о чем я вам написал в своем первом комментарии.

Comment: Я вас понял, еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Vadim удачи вам.